# Google place picker api, occur error in the searching process

Tags: android

Good Day,

I'm trying to use place picker api. From [google](https://developers.google.com/places/android/).

```
    public void onPickButtonClick(View v) {
    // Construct an intent for the place picker
    try {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder =
            new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(this);
        // Start the intent by requesting a result,
        // identified by a request code.
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER);

    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // ...
    }


    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
        int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER
        && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        // The user has selected a place. Extract the name and address.
        final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);

        final CharSequence name = place.getName();
        final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
        String attributions = PlacePicker.getAttributions(data);
        if (attributions == null) {
            attributions = "";
        }

        mViewName.setText(name);
        mViewAddress.setText(address);
        mViewAttributions.setText(Html.fromHtml(attributions));

    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

But it result in that after launching the application loading the places. It just flash and turn white and return to the page where i launch this application.

Thank You In Advance

**code**

```
   public class POI extends ActionBarActivity {
int REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER = 1;
TextView mViewName, mViewAddress, mViewAttributions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_poi_horizontal);


    mViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    mViewAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
    mViewAttributions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.attributions);


}

public void PickButtonClick(View v) {
    // Construct an intent for the place picker
    try {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder =
                new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(this);
        // Start the intent by requesting a result,
        // identified by a request code.
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER);

    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // ...
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER
            && resultCode == POI.RESULT_OK) {

        // The user has selected a place. Extract the name and address.
        final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);

        final CharSequence name = place.getName();
        final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
        String attributions = PlacePicker.getAttributions(data);
        if (attributions == null) {
            attributions = "";
        }

        mViewName.setText(name);
        mViewAddress.setText(address);
        mViewAttributions.setText(Html.fromHtml(attributions));

    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_poi, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: what is error. please post logcat.

Comment: Haii, Thank for replying. It didn't had any error.
When it's launch it simply goes to the page where google show suggestions.And next moment it return to the activity page in android where my button launch the following code. Instantly

Comment: @Shvet 
Maybe you were right there are error. 

This was shown on my log mark red.



06-02 17:09:03.652    4185-4185/com.example.itrack11 E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza

Comment: After debugging i realise my variable "data" in the method/function of onActivityResult == null. Could that be the cause?

Comment: put one check in if `(requestCode == REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER
        && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data!=null)`.

Comment: @Shvet. Hai =D

Thank you for your suggestion. I've replace 
if (requestCode == REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER
                && resultCode == POI.RESULT_OK) In my onActivityResult to 

if (requestCode == REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER
                && resultCode == POI.RESULT_OK && data!=null)

Still same thing happen. :(

Comment: I realise this code   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); The if is being skip because null is being detected. Therefore the data is being detected as null and the application close and return to the activity page. This is my current guess. But i can't remove data variable as well. I require it to get my the name and address of user selection. ='(

Comment: Hello, @hamham. Could you please put part of your Manifest file on your description? I had the same problem and discovered that i wrote "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" wrong on the manifest.

Comment: Thank you for your kind respond @GeorgeR my problem that i discovered it crashes with another api from google that i declare in the manifest.